# Trying to create a single graphic with 4 lines representing 4 data frames in a file

Tags: r

[My file looks something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC80r.png)
My file looks something like this:

```
Student,      HW Average,    Weekly Quiz Average,    Grade (Midterm)
1,            94,          82,               87
2,            78,          75,               79
3,            83,          72,               79
4,            97,          94,               96
5,            98,          93,               96
6,            97,          88,               93
7,            93,          88,               91
8,            77,          58,               72
9,            85,          71,               78
10,           96,          79,               90
To 66
```

The code I tried using was the following.

```
library(readr)
Students <- read_csv("Julies_Data.csv", quote = ",")

library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Students=r(2...66))
new.df <- NULL
for (i in seq(2, ncol(df), 2)) {
  new.df <- rbind(new.df,
      data.frame(no=i/2,
        "HW Average"         = df[, i],
        "Weekly Quiz Average"= df[, i+1],
        "Grade Midterm"      = df[, i+2]))
}

qplot("HW Average", "Weekly Quiz Average", "Grade Midterm",
  group=no, data=new.df, col=factor(no), geom="line")
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now? Please explain what your current result is and how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: The image of your data is neither desired (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272) nor necessary since you have the sample data. You provide some code that looks feasible but it not legal ... what is `r(2...66)`?

Comment: I tried to fix your braces and indentation, you had a dangling brace and to improve legibility. Also `r(2...66)` is another syntax error. Please post code that actually runs. I also think you made a mistake in iterating over *columns* of df instead of *rows*, nor why the step of 2 `for (i in seq(2, ncol(df), 2))`. And anyway it's unnecessary and slow to use for-loops to iteratively append a row(?) slice of your df. You can just directly assign the entire 2D slice: `new.df <- df[ , 2:4]` or whatever, then fix up `row.names(new.df)` and `names(df)`.

Comment: And you don't even need to explicitly say `df[1:nrow(df), 2:4]` when taking a row-slice, `df[, 2:4]` is understood to mean that. Please read [the documentation R-lang.html Section 3.4 Indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing)